# Quasar q-date component, how to disable double click?

Tags: vue.js, quasar, qdate

I need to disable the double-click action on the Q-Date Quasar control but there is no reference on the documentation.

There is a way to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@dblclick.native.prevent.stop` if it's a `<q-something>` component.

`@dblclick.prevent.stop` if it's a regular HTML element

Comment: This code must be inserted directly into the tag?

Comment: yes that's right, for example `<some-q-thingy @dblclick.native.prevent.stop />`